# Finding the index of an element of specific column in python list

Tags: python, list, arraylist

```
table= [['','n','+','*','(',')','$'],
        ['E',1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1],
        ['R',-1, 3, 2, -1, 2, 2],
        ['T',4, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1],
        ['S',-1, 5, 6, -1, 5, 5],
        ['F',7, -1, -1, 8, -1, -1]]
```

I want to find the index of 'E' using `table.index()` function in column 1 and index should be 0. How can I get this?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically logic work as first convert it into `1d list` which can be done using `python inbuilt` functionality or using `numpy module` `reshape function` for easiness.  And then find the index using `t[0].index('E')` and then format result `(ind % 7, ind // 7))`.

**CODE :**

**METHOD-1 :**

```
table= [['','n','+','*','(',')','$'],
        ['E',1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1],
        ['R',-1, 3, 2, -1, 2, 2],
        ['T',4, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1],
        ['S',-1, 5, 6, -1, 5, 5],
        ['F',7, -1, -1, 8, -1, -1]]

c='F'
index=[(i, fruits.index(c)) for i, fruits in enumerate(table) if c in fruits]
print(index)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[(5, 0)]
```

**METHOD-2 :**

```
table = [['', 'n', '+', '*', '(', ')', '$'], ['E', 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1],
         ['R', -1, 3, 2, -1, 2, 2], ['T', 4, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1],
         ['S', -1, 5, 6, -1, 5, 5], ['F', 7, -1, -1, 8, -1, -1]]


import numpy as np

t = np.array(table).reshape(1, 42).tolist()
ind = t[0].index('E')
print(ind)
print('(Row_Number, Column_Number) = ', (ind % 7, ind // 7))
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
(Row_Number, Column_Number) =  (0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index()` on `table` after you located the correct sublist. Add condition if `'E'` in the list to avoid `ValueError`. `next` will return the first result if exists, else default `None`

```
result = next(([table.index(t), t.index('E')] for t in table if 'E' in t), None)
```

`result` will be `[1, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

Here `x` will equal the first row that contains 'E', then you can `table.index(x)` will return the row index and `x.index(val)` will return the column index.

```
val = 'E'
      
x = [x for x in table if val in x][0]

print([table.index(x), x.index(val)])
```

This solution will print `[1, 0]`.

Comment: Use want (X, Y) pair of location of `E` in table

Answer (score 0):

```
find = 'E'
for row in range(len(table)):
    if find in table[row]:
        print(row, table[row].index(find))
```